# kwargs.get() not retrieving a value

Tags: python-3.x, keyword-argument

I'm attempting to pull in a value from Python 3's `kwargs`, but failing and I'm having a very difficult time understanding why.

The code:

```
def parse_config(**kwargs):
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    _config = kwargs.get('configfile', os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), '.dakcs_rsync.json'))
    print('Config file: {}'.format(_config))
```

The results:

```
Linux$ /home/user/tmp/rs.py -c
> /home/user/tmp/rs.py(226)parse_config()
-> _config = kwargs.get('configfile', os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), '.rs.json'))
(Pdb) kwargs
{'configfile': None}
(Pdb) kwargs.get('configfile')
(Pdb) kwargs.get('configfile', 'blah')
(Pdb) _test = kwargs.get('configfile', 'foo')
(Pdb) print(repr(_test))
None
(Pdb) _test
(Pdb) sys.version_info
sys.version_info(major=3, minor=4, micro=9, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
(Pdb)
```

Why isn't `kwargs.get()` retrieving the value for the `configfile` key as I expect?

Answer (score 0):

I found my own answer while hashing through it in my head.

`dict.get()` retrieves a default value IF THE KEY DOES NOT EXIST.  It does exist in this case, but it's value is `None`.  I'd always thought it would give you a default value if the value did not exist or was `None`.  I was wrong.